# Client cannot access their web site from certain locations

Tags: ubuntu

We're hosting a web site for a client on our dedicated server (Ubuntu 8.10) but from certain places (including their main office) they cannot get the web site to load. We transferred the domain and hosting from another company to ourselves back in November and the problems have been since then, sporadically.

- I can access the site with no problems.
- They can access other sites fine.
- They can also access other websites hosted on the server so it's not a server-wide thing.
- I have checked other sources (like downforeveryone....) and haven't found any problems.

What could be the problem? What other things should I look at?

Comment: Sounds like a DNS problem. I would check/test/verify their DNS settings. Do the DNS records for the site resolve correctly from the client's network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do they have a local DNS server with the IP pointing at the wrong place? Or a hosts file? If they run "ping www.website.com" does it resolve to the right ip?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you have a small number of machines doing the DNS resolution, and one of them is still pointing to the old location.

I can think of a few ways this could happen:

- All internal machines use one internal server as their DNS server; it in turn is configured to send queries via two servers, one of which happens to be the old hosting company's server, which still has the domain configured and pointing at the old company's web servers
- All internal machines have their web traffic sent through one of three proxy servers; one of the servers has a hosts file entry pointing to the old web server